# html email signature to resize for iphone/smaller screenn

Tags: ios, responsive-design, html-email

I'm designing a basic HTML signature.  I do the HTML code in Dreamweaver (Mac), open to preview in firefox/safari and select all and drag the HTML into apple mails signature composer. It works well, and the signature looks good on desktop and ipad but doesen't work on iphone/smaller screen.

The signature looks like this (i've blacked out personal details):
[image]

The problem is on the smaller iphone, some of the text stays left of the picture, and some does not fit and ends up under the photo but with a margin.  What would be ideal is if on iphone, I could config so all text and icons display below the main picture all the way left with no margin.  Is it possible to set a different set CSS styles for iphone in a HTML email? or is there another way I can make my code more responsive?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


</head>
<body>

 <div id="sig-container" style="margin-top: 15px;padding-top: 6px; border-top: 1px dashed #ddd;">
 <div style="float: left; margin: 2px 10px 5px 0px; border-right: 2px solid #000; padding-right: 30px; display: block;" id="photoWrapper"> <img src="http://websiteremoved/emailsm.jpg" id="sigPhoto" height="300px" width="200px"> </div> 
 <div style="margin-top:0px; margin-left: 74px;" id="sigDetailsWrapper"> <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; line-height: 10px; color: #333; margin-top:10; margin-left:0; padding-left:0;"> <strong><span id="sigName">Name Removed</span></strong></span> <br>
 <span id="sigTitle"><p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 0px; color: #333; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:20px;margin-left:0; padding-left:0;">Title Removed | Title Removed</span><br> 
 <div><p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; color: #333;">
 <span> email: <a href="mailto:emailremoved" id="sigEmail" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;">emailremoved </a></span> <br>
  <span> mobile: <a href="tel:mobileremoved" id="sigMobile" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;">mobileremoved </a></span><br>
  <span> web:  <a href="http://websiteremoved" id="sigWebsite" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"   rel="nofollow">websiteremoved</a></span> <br>
 <span>  facebook: <a href="http://facebook.com/facebookremoved" id="sigfb" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"  rel="nofollow">facebook.com/facebookremoved</a></span> <br> <br>
  <a href="tel:phonenumberremoved"><img src="http://websiteremoved/phone.jpg" height="62px" width="62px" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"  rel="nofollow"></a>
  <a href="http://websiteremoved/fb.jpg" height="62px" width="62px" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"  rel="nofollow"></a>
  <a href="mailto:emailremoved"><img src="http://websiteremoved/email.jpg" height="62px" width="62px" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"  rel="nofollow"></a>
  <a href="http://websiteremoved"><img src="http://websiteremoved/web.jpg" height="62px" width="62px" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"  rel="nofollow"></a>  </p> </div>  

<div class="sep about" style="box-sizing: border-box;
background-attachment: scroll; height: 120px; position: relative; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; 
background-image: 
url('http://websiteremoved/about-sep.jpg');
 z-index: 1; background-position: 50% -48.5px; background-repeat: 
no-repeat no-repeat; "></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can target iPhones using their retina screens. The media query should be "@media all and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)" For example...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
@media all and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) { 
    #sigDetailsWrapper {margin-left: 0px !important;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="sig-container" style="margin-top: 15px;padding-top: 6px; border-top: 1px dashed #ddd;">
 <div style="float: left; margin: 2px 10px 5px 0px; border-right: 2px solid #000; padding-right: 30px; display: block;" id="photoWrapper"> <img src="http://websiteremoved/emailsm.jpg" id="sigPhoto" height="300px" width="200px"> </div> 
 <div style="margin-top:0px; margin-left: 74px;" id="sigDetailsWrapper"> <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; line-height: 10px; color: #333; margin-top:10; margin-left:0; padding-left:0;"> <strong><span id="sigName">Name Removed</span></strong></span> <br>
 <span id="sigTitle"><p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 0px; color: #333; margin-top:0; margin-bottom:20px;margin-left:0; padding-left:0;">Title Removed | Title Removed</span><br> 
 <div><p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; color: #333;">
 <span> email: <a href="mailto:emailremoved" id="sigEmail" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;">emailremoved </a></span> <br>
  <span> mobile: <a href="tel:mobileremoved" id="sigMobile" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;">mobileremoved </a></span><br>
  <span> web:  <a href="http://websiteremoved" id="sigWebsite" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"   rel="nofollow">websiteremoved</a></span> <br>
 <span>  facebook: <a href="http://facebook.com/facebookremoved" id="sigfb" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"  rel="nofollow">facebook.com/facebookremoved</a></span> <br> <br>
  <a href="tel:phonenumberremoved"><img src="http://websiteremoved/phone.jpg" height="62px" width="62px" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"  rel="nofollow"></a>
  <a href="http://websiteremoved/fb.jpg" height="62px" width="62px" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"  rel="nofollow"></a>
  <a href="mailto:emailremoved"><img src="http://websiteremoved/email.jpg" height="62px" width="62px" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"  rel="nofollow"></a>
  <a href="http://websiteremoved"><img src="http://websiteremoved/web.jpg" height="62px" width="62px" style="color:#428BCA; text-decoration: none;"  rel="nofollow"></a>  </p> </div>  

<div class="sep about" style="box-sizing: border-box;
background-attachment: scroll; height: 120px; position: relative; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; 
background-image: 
url('http://websiteremoved/about-sep.jpg');
 z-index: 1; background-position: 50% -48.5px; background-repeat: 
no-repeat no-repeat; "></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You might want to recode this to use tables, though, as divs can often get messed up in Outlook, as well as Floats.